# How to handle database information changes with links using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a website with a product page that displays information about the product which is generated by product.php using a GET on productname and getting information from a MySQL database. Now, occasionally product names will change. This will happen rarely but it will happen.

After the name change, old links to www.website.com/product.php?productname=Toaster400 will no longer work obviously. However, I would like for these links to redirect to the correct page. I would also like to allow people to search for "Toaster400" even though the corrected name is "Toaster400a".

I have thought of only one solution which is to have an table in MySQL of 'old names.' If a product is not found in the Product table, then I could check the 'old names' table and see which product that old name is related to.

Is this the best way of appraching this? Thank you.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here's the code:

```
//This just initializes the database connection
require __DIR__ . "/resources/database.php";

//checks to see if they searched for anything
if(isset($_GET['search_text'])) {
    $name = $_GET['search_text'];

    $db = getDbConnection();
    //This is a stored procedure which is literally just a select for % . ? . %
    $stmt = $db->prepare("CALL get_products(?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 150);
    $isQueryOk = $stmt->execute();
    $results = array();
```

The code then checks how many rows were returned and redirects accordingly.

Comment: user ther id in the url

Comment: But that doesn't help when a user searches. When they search for an old product name they should be directed to the correct page. The ID would help with URL's but it wouldn't for searching, unless there's something I'm missing.

Comment: How does your search function work? Are you just plunking the string the user searched for into the URL? Shame on you! ;)

Comment: Is there a better way? I'm new to this!

Comment: I think it will help us here to give you a solution if you can add your code, like your query or your php code when you redirect etc

Comment: @Rifai My PHP code just connects to a MySQL database and selects from the Product table all rows containing their search query. If there's more than 1 it will redirect to a page which displays all results. If there's only 1 result it redirects to the product page displaying the product information.

Comment: Is it possible for you to edit your question to include that code, please? A description is but vaguely helpful; to see the code itself would be ideal.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang Ok, I put it up. If there's anything else let me know!

Comment: product name can change, it's update data, or delete and make new as a substitute ?

Comment: @Rifai the problem is I want to keep compatibility with the older product names, the other information doesn't matter.

Comment: ok, so it's update data right ?
what I meant, if you delete and create new product it will consider as a new product. although in reality it's same product.

it's take effect when you define where is old product and new product, the even is when you update data. right or not ? 
sorry if my english language is terrible. :D

Comment: its fine! i know how to update the data but the problem is when I update it, the old name is overwritten so I can't refer to the old name anymore.

Comment: I think your idea of creating a separate "product history" table is the best option, along with Dagon's recommendation to use product id's instead of names in your URL's. Also in the product history table, you could add the date of when the name was changed, deleted, etc, if you ever need that data. You may also want to look into triggers so the data will be updated automatically upon any change.

Comment: make new table for history, contains id_product and old name.
before update new data, insert into table history your old product name and product_id
so, if any searching data in table product not found you can search in table history, if found. you can get the new product name using product id.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider 'tags' column in the table for a product. For example:

### table column

```
id->1
Product name-> test
tags->test
```

### after update, value of column will be

```
id->1
product name->testupdate
tags->test, testupdate
```

and by doing this, you can search renamed product. Hope this helps.:)

Answer (score 0):

table product : product_id, product_name, description, etc.

table history : product_id, product_name

url : example.com/../sample_name

```
select * from product where product_name='sample_name'
```

if not found

```
select * from history h
left join product p on h.product_id=p.product_id
where h.product_name='sample_name'
```